# How can I link Google Calendar to an application?

Tags: java, android, calendar

For example: If today is Dec 25 I want the app to automatically update its status as Holiday. So the idea is to change the change the status of the application depending on the status of the day. So i thought since Google calendar has the statuses of days it would be easy to link its statuses to my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucky for you google have great documentation on the API's they provided so your app will be able to "talk" with the calendar app.
I would start by doing [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) walk-through guide.